# Does distance formula work for arbitrary vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

The task is the following:

In the space $\Bbb R^3$, the standard inner product $(x, y) = x^T y$ is given, and three vectors are given:
$$
p_1 = (1, 4, 0)^T, p_2 = (−1, 4, 4)^T, p_3 = (6, 8, 0)^T.
$$
Let $L$ be the hyperplane passing through points $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$. Determine
the distance from the hyperplane $L$ to the following vectors:
$$
w_1 = (1, 3, 5)^T, w_2 = (3, 8, 3)^T
$$

I tried to solve this using the Gram matrix determinant formula:

the hyperplane is spanned by $v_1 = p_2 - p_1 = (-2, 0, 4)^T, v_2 = p_3 - p_1 = (5, 4, 0)^T$.
Using the formula
$$
    \rho(L, w_1) = \sqrt{\frac{\det(G(v_1, v_2, w_1))}{\det(G(v_1, v_2))}} \;
    G = A^TA;
     \det(G(v_1, v_2, w_1))
     = 720; \\
     \rho(L, w_1) = \sqrt{\frac{16}{720}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{5}}
$$

But the answer should be $\sqrt 5$ for the first one and $2/\sqrt 5$ for the second one.

I don’t get what I am doing wrong, the formula about should be applicable, and the only restriction a.f.a.i.k. is the linear independece of the vectors.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking about the relation between the distance matrix and the Gram matrix. But the question you have posed is not related to that. You may want to check out the following: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_plane

Comment: @AnuragA the question is rather: why is this method not working here, are there any other limitaions on vectors apart form linear independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.
As a vector subspace of dimension two, it is a plane that
passes through the origin of the vector space, $(0,0,0)$.

The plane through $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$, however, does **not** pass through $(0,0,0)$.
Because these three vectors are linearly independent, the only subspace of $\mathbb R^3$
that contains all three vectors is the entire space $\mathbb R^3$ itself.

So you are dealing with two different planes in this question:
the original plane through $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$,
and the plane through $(0,0,0)$ spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.
The two planes are parallel to each other, but the distance from $w_1$ (or $w_2$)
to one plane is not necessarily equal to the distance to the other plane.

You are measuring the distance to the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.
That's why you get the wrong answer.

Comment: What do you suggest I do in this case. Do you think this formula is not applicable at all in this case? 

I was thinking about moving the plane towards the origin and moving $w_1$ accordingly, but in this case I would have to know the distance from the origin to my plane, which means I got into recursion)

Comment: I usually do something with a unit vector perpendicular to the plane. Another thing you might try is to translate the entire space (including all the vectors) so that $p_1$ becomes the origin. Then the subspace will be the correct plane to measure a distance from.